# Задать интервал графика

Tags: math, mathematica, oxyplot, formula

Всем привет. Строю график. Нужна формула, которая на основании минимального и максимального значений задаёт интервал (шаг) между отсчётами. То бишь допустим, что макс=95; мин=8; интервал при этом, примерно, должен составлять около ~5. Или же макс=672; мин=35; интервал при этом, примерно, должен составлять ~50. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Берёшь разность, делишь на желаемое количество промежуточных отсчётов, ищешь ближайшее к нему стандартное (набор составляешь сам, например, 1, 2, 2.5, 4, 5) с точностью до порядка. *допустим, что макс=95; мин=8;*, разность 87, при желаемом количестве отсчётов около 10 точный шаг 7.9, а ближайший стандартный 5 или  1*10. *макс=672; мин=35;*, разность 647, для 10 отсчётов точный шаг 57.9, ближайший стандартный 5*10.